# Is it fine to have one table with foreign keys to many other tables?

Tags: sql, performance, foreign-keys, multiple-columns, database-schema

Let's say that I have 30 tables in my database which all have a one-to-many relationship to a `Notations` table:

What is another way to set up the `Notations` table (other than containing a foreign key column for each of its "parents") that would be less taxing to the query's performance? The table is expected to grow to be very large.

(As each Notation contains a single parent_table_id with 29 null values for the remaining parent_tables - that is 29 nulls to track for every row, it seems like a lot)

ie.
`SELECT text, table1_id, table2_id, ..., table30_id FROM Notations` would show:

```
id         text         table1_id       table2_id      //     table30_id
0          "buzz"       74              null           //     null
1          "foo"        null            45             //     null
2          "bar"        22              null           //     null
3          "fizz"       22              null           //     null
4          "hello"      28              null           //     null
5          "world"      null            null           //     3
...etc
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I believe [dba.se] might be a better site for this sort of question (Not to say it's completely off-topic here, rather you might get better results there)

Comment: Please ask exactly 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question per post. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Follow an appropriate published/authoritative textbook/manual/reference. Ask 1 question re where you got stuck.

Comment: Re "efficient": Learn the basics of relational & SQL optimization/implementation/performance by query engines in general via textbooks & the web & SO & in particular via DBMS manual--all immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. PS There's no "best" in engineering. Define it in enough detail & give enough relevant details that all would agree on a valuation. Even if that could be done it's too much for a question here. And then you would need to explain why you can't evaluate that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the primer, @philipxy, I will take these to heart and I have reworded my question.  Through my education in Databases, I have learned my approach as the only one, but have not been able to find a solution to connecting to many tables having to list each column of reference.  I believe there are other approaches out there that people more than just myself would like to know.

Comment: I can't make out what this post is trying to ask. PS Do you mean M:1? What is "make sense"? Putting a word in quotes doesn't make clear what you mean by it. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that storing 30 columns where one is not `NULL` is inefficient -- those `NULL` values typically occupy space in each row.

Assuming all the ids are the same type, you can simplify the structure to use:

```
table_name
table_id
```

Just two columns.  Unfortunately, I am not aware of any database that allows "conditional" foreign key relationships.  Although I advocate defining foreign key relationships this might be a case where you choose not to have them.

That is not fully satisfying.  Although you can ensure some integrity using triggers, this lacks the "cascading" features of foreign keys.  You can implement that with more triggers.  Yuck!

One alternative is a separate notations table for each table:

```
notations_table1
    text, id

notations_table2
    text, id

. . .
```

You can then bring these together using `union all`:

```
create view notations as (
    select text, id, 'table1' as table_name from notaions_table1 union all
    select text, id, 'table2' as table_name from notaions_table2 union all
    . . .
```

The underlying tables can then have properly formatted foreign key constraints -- and even cascading ones.  Unfortunately, this lacks a single column as an `id`.  The "real" id is a combination of `table_name` and `id`.

Some databases have other mechanisms that  might be able to help.  For instance, Postgres supports a form of inheritance that might be useful in this context.

Comment: Thanks @gordon, this helps me very much!

Comment: @DavidDiRico . . . If this answers your question, you can consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You shouldn't have a notations table**

The point of a primary-foreign key pair is that the value of the foreign key is the same as the value of the primary. A notations table does not make sense. Normalisation is an extremely important aspects of databases. We want to reduce redundant and replicated data. **We don't want repetition!** A notations table would introduce redundant data. In this case redundant data can refer to data we can calculate with existing data. All tables to be normalised must only contain data that relates to itself and not be calculable.

We can calculate each link due to check if foreign key field are filled and the key exists in the related table. Hence these links do not suit being in a separate table. As you mention this would be an enormous table and that's for the very reason it is only holding redundant data. There is no need for a notations table. Rather if you need to find links then just write a query to check for matches between primary and foreign keys. That is the reason why databases use foreign keys.

A notations table is only appropriate if we did not have any foreign keys. We would then require a table to tell us how each record relates to another record in a different table. But since you do have foreign keys then this table is causing repeated and redundant data.